# Should an employer file a tax withholding exemption form for non-resident workers?

Tags: united-states, taxes, income-tax, non-resident

I'm classified as a non-resident alien because I don't pass the Green Card Test or the Substantial Presence Test. My income is, according to [this](http://www.irs.gov/Individuals/International-Taxpayers/Nonresident-Aliens---Source-of-Income), not U.S. based, even though I get money from an U.S. employer, because the services are performed in another country.

What tax withholding exemption form should my employer have?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not subject to the US tax laws, and since the income is not US-sourced, it is not subject to withholding. Your employer doesn't need any form, but if they insist - you can provide them a W8-BEN to certify your non-resident status.

Keep in mind that if you do come to the US, the money you earn while in the US **is** US-sourced and subject to the US taxes and withholding, even if you're non-resident.

Comment: Alright, thanks for all the help (here and previously). If I can trouble you (hopefully) one last time, is there anything that prevents me from using my American debit card abroad with the funds of my employment?

Comment: (Of course I'll pay local income taxes)

Comment: Nothing in the US law. Check with your local law, some countries don't allow these things because it's an easy way to evade taxes.